# Custom font (file) not applying in TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, tailwind-css

I can't get the custom font to work in tailwind CSS. I've tried utilizing chat GPT, stack overflow (other posts), reddit, etc. I can't figure it out. It's just not working.

I've tried locating the file path using ./ instead of / and even tried ../ but it's not showing up in my console's network resources. Not sure if it's relevant. I tried using  and directly styling the body element in the header, didn't take it. I've tried so many different methods. Cleared cache, confirmed TTF isn't corrupt, I can go on for hours about how much I've tried figuring this just out of stubbornness. I can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;

    @font-face {
      font-family: "robotoMono";
      src: url("../resources/fonts/robotoMono.ttf");
    }
```

```
    module.exports = {
      content: [`./{html, js}`],
      theme: {
        extend: {
          fontFamily: {
            robotoMono: [`robotoMono`, `sans-serif`],
          },
        },
      },
      plugins: [],
    };
```

```
<body class="font-roboto">
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="title"><h1>Password Generator</h1></div>
```

/resources/fonts/robotoMono (see attached image)

I've tried applying the font styles directly to the h1 element as well. The font isn't changing at all. There's a quick little glitch that happens when hitting save (in my browser's live server) but it's like less than a second where the font changes and then reverts back to the original font. Not sure if this is relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named the font "robotoMono". Therefore, font-roboto won't work.

Use **class="font-robotoMono"** instead.

If that doesn't work, consider this:

```
<body class="font-['robotoMono`]">
```

Comment: I've tried that (somewhere along the renaming I forgot to make the class robotoMono as well because originally they all started as roboto and that didn't work) but just to make sure, I tried again. Still not updating the font. I'm so over this font file method lol

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Does the @font-face recognize the source? Maybe it's not tailwind's fault.

Comment: Never mind. I re-ran the build from scratch and now it works.